# How to explain `False == x && True == x`

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions, logic

Execute the following code:

```
   Clear[d1, d2, x, y, dd]
   d1 = EmpiricalDistribution[{6, 65/10, 7, 75/10, 8}];
   d2 = EmpiricalDistribution[{3, 45/10, 6, 75/10, 9, 105/10, 12, 135/10}];
   dd = TransformedDistribution[x > y, {x \[Distributed] d1, y \[Distributed] d2}];
   PDF[dd, x]
```

in the result, I find a strange thing:

```
 3/8   False != x && True == x   
 5/8   False == x && True != x
 1     False == x && True == x
 0      True
```

for this, I have some doubts about `False == x && True == x`.

How to explain this thing

Comment: I don't believe that `expr` in [`TransformedDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedDistribution.html) can be an inequality. You can however calculate the [`Probability`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Probability.html) of the inequality being `True`:  `p = Probability[x > y, {x \[Distributed] d1, y \[Distributed] d2}]` evaluates to `3/8`

Comment: Hi Bob Hanlon; can you flesh that out a bit, so I can upvote?

Comment: @bobbym - you need to use `@username` to have the user receive a notification. Also in `@username` all spaces need to be removed from the user name.

Comment: @BobHanlon. I thought you were still hanging around so I got lazyl. My apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Clear[d1, d2, x, y, dd]
d1 = EmpiricalDistribution[{6, 65/10, 7, 75/10, 8}];
d2 = EmpiricalDistribution[{3, 45/10, 6, 75/10, 9, 105/10, 12, 135/10}];
```

The `expr` in [`TransformedDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedDistribution.html), e.g., `TransformedDistribution[expr, {Subscript[x, 1] \[Distributed] Subscript[dist, 1], Subscript[x, 2] \[Distributed] Subscript[dist, 2] , …}]` should be a function of the random variables rather than a predicate (Boolean-valued expression such as an inequality). For a predicate you would use [`Probability`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Probability.html) to determine the probability of the event represented by the predicate:  `Probability[pred, {Subscript[x, 1] \[Distributed] Subscript[dist, 1], Subscript[x, 2] \[Distributed] Subscript[dist, 2], …}]`

```
dd = TransformedDistribution[
   x - y, {x \[Distributed] d1, y \[Distributed] d2}];

pdf = PDF[dd, x]

(*  1/40 Boole[6 == 3 + x] + 1/40 Boole[6 == 9/2 + x] + 1/40 Boole[6 == 6 + x] + 
 1/40 Boole[6 == 15/2 + x] + 1/40 Boole[6 == 9 + x] + 
 1/40 Boole[6 == 21/2 + x] + 1/40 Boole[6 == 12 + x] + 
 1/40 Boole[6 == 27/2 + x] + 1/40 Boole[13/2 == 3 + x] + 
 1/40 Boole[13/2 == 9/2 + x] + 1/40 Boole[13/2 == 6 + x] + 
 1/40 Boole[13/2 == 15/2 + x] + 1/40 Boole[13/2 == 9 + x] + 
 1/40 Boole[13/2 == 21/2 + x] + 1/40 Boole[13/2 == 12 + x] + 
 1/40 Boole[13/2 == 27/2 + x] + 1/40 Boole[7 == 3 + x] + 
 1/40 Boole[7 == 9/2 + x] + 1/40 Boole[7 == 6 + x] + 
 1/40 Boole[7 == 15/2 + x] + 1/40 Boole[7 == 9 + x] + 
 1/40 Boole[7 == 21/2 + x] + 1/40 Boole[7 == 12 + x] + 
 1/40 Boole[7 == 27/2 + x] + 1/40 Boole[15/2 == 3 + x] + 
 1/40 Boole[15/2 == 9/2 + x] + 1/40 Boole[15/2 == 6 + x] + 
 1/40 Boole[15/2 == 15/2 + x] + 1/40 Boole[15/2 == 9 + x] + 
 1/40 Boole[15/2 == 21/2 + x] + 1/40 Boole[15/2 == 12 + x] + 
 1/40 Boole[15/2 == 27/2 + x] + 1/40 Boole[8 == 3 + x] + 
 1/40 Boole[8 == 9/2 + x] + 1/40 Boole[8 == 6 + x] + 
 1/40 Boole[8 == 15/2 + x] + 1/40 Boole[8 == 9 + x] + 
 1/40 Boole[8 == 21/2 + x] + 1/40 Boole[8 == 12 + x] + 
 1/40 Boole[8 == 27/2 + x]  *)
```

Then for the distribution of `x-y` the probability that `x > y` is

```
1 - CDF[dd, 0]

(*  3/8  *)
```

Or using `Probability`

```
p = Probability[x > y, {x \[Distributed] d1, y \[Distributed] d2}]

(*  3/8  *)
```

Comment: thanks for the follow up, it clears up some problems for me. +1

Answer (score 1):

It seems the code produced by `TransformedDistribution[x > y,..]` calculates the probability accurately, even if it contains impossible cases and redundant conditions for the intended input.  It is, of course, a discrete PDF.  The input should be Boolean, either `True` or `False`.

Note `PDF[dd]` or `PDF[dd][x]` produces a somewhat more sensible-looking function.

```
PDF[dd][x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The following will simplify the extraneous conditions in the OP's `PDF[dd, x]`.  It seems hard to get rid of the last one (the default), without rewriting the expression.  (This is true in general about the default case of `Piecewise`.)

```
Simplify[PDF[dd, x], TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, Reduce[#, x] &}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And an explicit value works fine, too:

```
PDF[dd, True]
(*  3/8  *)
```